# ROS2 Rviz Error : Global Status Warn Fixed Frame No tf data. Actual error: Frame [world] does not exist

Tags: ros2, rviz

I am controlling a KUKA iiwa 14 robot using ROS2 Galactic and the nodes I found here:
[KUKA iiwa 14 Package](https://github.com/ICube-Robotics/iiwa_ros2)

It worked fine but suddenly I can't open the robot with rviz anymore. I get the Error:

> "Fixed Frame
> No tf data. Actual error: Frame [world] does not exist"

and I don't see the robot in rviz anymore.

The solutions I could find are using ros1 and rosrun, which is not supported for ros2.

I would be very thankful for any advice.

[image]